# I can't connect to S3 from the Kubernetes pod when the bucket name is longer than 14 characters

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file using my spring boot app from a pod to Amazon S3 storage. Last year this setup worked without any problems, but now I'm getting an error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: custom-bucket-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

This spring boot app works when I run it locally, but once deployed to a Kubernetes cluster it can't get through. When I tried to ping the above address it worked from my local machine, but when I logged into a pod and tried to ping it I got

```
ping custom-bucket-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
ping: bad address "custom-bucket-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

What's interesting is when I try a shorter bucket name or another long address it works, e.g.:

```
ping short-name.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
64 bytes from 3.5.62.11: seq=0 ttl=63 time=43.670 ms

ping llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch.co.uk
64 bytes from 109.70.148.44: seq=0 ttl=63 time=51.668 ms
```

**Do you know what could be causing this? Is there any way to fix this other than creating a shorter bucket name?**

PS
env: latest Desktop and Kubernetes,
Docker Desktop: 4.27.1 (136059)
Engine: 25.0.2
Kubernetes: 1.29.1